# how to dynamically disable specific date in jquery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to dynamically disable date (jquery datepicker) which is already in database. I have done static method in that I am able to achieve goal but not getting success in dynamic approach

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var getfromdb = @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.bookdate);
    var result = '\'' + getfromdb.toString().split(',').join('\',\'') + '\'';
    var disableddates = [result];

    var newdisableddates = ['17/10/2017','18/10/2017','19/10/2017','22/10/2017','23/10/2017','24/10/2017','25/10/2017'];  // Static Approach 

    $("#txtFromdate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
    $("#txtTodate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });

    function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
        return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
});
```

And here is my controller code:

```
    List<string> getbookdate = new List<string>();
    getbookdate = BookDate(id);
    ViewBag.bookdate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getbookdate.ToList());


     public List<string> BookDate(int? id)
        {
            DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Now.Date;
            var getbookdate = (from x in entity.BookingMasters
                               join
                               y in entity.BookingDetails on x.BookingId equals y.BookingId
                               where x.ProductId == id && y.FromDate > dt && y.ToDate > dt
                               select new BookingModel { ProductId = x.ProductId.Value, FromDate = y.FromDate.Value, ToDate = y.ToDate.Value }).ToList();

            List<string> allDates = new List<string>();

            foreach (var r in getbookdate)
            {
                for (DateTime date = r.FromDate; date <= r.ToDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
                {
                    allDates.Add(Convert.ToString(date.ToShortDateString()));
                }
            }
            return allDates;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable doesn't work well with date picker. Try my plnkr.

https://embed.plnkr.co/h4RaeIKJVfj9IjyHREqZ/

It gets the datepicker on click and parses through the dates and data set given and if a match is found it removes the click event on it. and repeats on each render please see my plnkr link for html. Hope it helps

```
<!--Disable doesn't work well with date picker. Try this. Hope it helps-->
<!--Working example https://embed.plnkr.co/h4RaeIKJVfj9IjyHREqZ/ -->
<!--Code-->
<!--HTML PART-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="tether@*" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.12.1" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.12.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="container">
  <h1>Hello User</h1>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label>Date:</label>
          <input type="text" id="date-picker-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var element = $('#date-picker-control');
    element.datepicker();

    element.off('click').on('click', function() {

      // Setup DatePicker
      console.log('Update Date Picker');

      // If user changes month or year, update date picker 
      // based on the date list you have 
      $("#ui-datepicker-div")
        .find("div.ui-datepicker-header")
        .find('a.ui-datepicker-next, a.ui-datepicker-prev')
        .on('click', function() {
          element.click();
        });

      // Get all available dates in current displayed dates
      var availableDates = $("#ui-datepicker-div")
        .find("table.ui-datepicker-calendar")
        .find('td[data-handler="selectDay"]');

      availableDates.filter(function(i) {
        var targetDateElement = $(this);

        //Get date parts
        var year = +targetDateElement.data("year");
        var month = targetDateElement.data("month") + 1; //JS fix
        var day = +targetDateElement.find('a.ui-state-default').text();
        var builtDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;

        // you can substitute your json data
        var targetDates = [
          "10/2/2017", "10/6/2017", "10/8/2017"
        ];

        $.each(targetDates, function(i, targetDate) {
          // If builtDate match targetdate then turn click event oFF on that date
          if (targetDate == builtDate) {
            targetDateElement.css({ 
              'border': '1px solid gray',
              'background': 'darkgray',    
              'font-weight': 'bold',
              'color': 'gray'
            }).off('click');
          }
        });

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you check my plnkr link. It works.. can you tell whats happening

Answer (score 0):

Your original idea is in the right direction, but I think there's probably something weird going on with all the string conversion.  I'd just pass through dates and compare with dates rather than all the stringy stuff:
I've written this quick test...

controller:

```
//Replace with however you get dates
 ViewBag.DatesList = new List<DateTime>() 
    { 
        new DateTime(2018, 01, 01), 
        new DateTime(2018, 01, 02), 
        new DateTime(2018, 01, 03) 
    };
    return View();
```

View:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

var disableddates = [];
@foreach (DateTime date in ViewBag.DatesList)
{
    //note JS month is zero-based for no good reason at all... 
    @:disableddates.push(new Date(@date.Year, @date.Month-1, @date.Day))
}

$("#txtFromdate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});
$("#txtTodate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});

function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
    //filter array to find any elements which have the date in.
    var filtereddates = disableddates.filter(function (d) {
        return d.getTime() === date.getTime();
    });

    //return array with TRUE as the first (only) element if there are NO 
    //matching dates - so a matching date in the array will tell calling 
    //code to disable that day.
    return [filtereddates.length == 0];
}
});
</script>
```

This appears to work for me.

Comment: Forgot to add - this will also work around problems with localisation (you original code assumes that ToShortDateString() will always return dates in the format you test for in JS which may not always be the case.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) : "The string returned by the ToShortDateString method is culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object."